# Converting Mod-rewrite rules which use %(QUERY_STRING) to NGINX rewrite format?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I've been stuck the last few days trying to convert the following Apache/Mod_Rewrite rewrite rule to NGINX format. Anyone know where I am going wrong?

MOD_REWRITE:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} topic=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule /forum/index\.php /forum/vbseo301.php?action=thread&oldid=%1 [L]
```

NGINX:

```
location /forum/index.php {
           if ($args ~ "topic=([0-9]+)"){
                        rewrite ^/forum/index\.php?topic=(.+)$ /forum/vbseo301.php?action=thread&oldid=$1 last;
                        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This does not answer the question -- please read the comment with more information** I am leaving this answer to host other variants of rewriting viable for other situations.

You can do it easier:

```
# At "server" level, NOT in "location"
rewrite ^/forum/index.php
         /forum/vbseo301.php?action=thread&oldid=$arg_topic?
        last;
```

The ? suffix tells Nginx to not append original arguments to the new URL.

**Sidenote**

By the way, if you are doing static mapping of one set of IDs to another, there is a more effective solution:

```
http {
  map $arg_topic $new_topic_id {
    default 1;
    2 3;
    4 65;
  }

  server {
    # some directives (server_name, listen, etc.) omitted

    rewrite ^/forum/index.php /forum/new.php?topic=$new_topic_id? last;

    # locations omitted
  }
}
```

`map` takes the first parameter (`topic` from query string in this case) and does a lookup through the table. It then assigns the result to the second parameter (`new_topic_id`). Two benefits:

- The lookup is very effective, as Nginx creates a hash table.
- The lookup occurs only when you are going to use `new_topic_id` (lazy evaluation)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I should provide some more information as I don't think this will work 100%:

1) I only want the redirect to take place if the the query parameter "topic" is present. 

Hence,
/forum/index.php?topic=72253 should redirect to /forum/vbseo301.php?action=thread&oldid=72253
 
but /forum/index.php should not be redirected at all.

2) Regarding your second comment about "static" mapping - by this I assume if you mean I have a list of topic IDs I can include right in the nginx CONF file? Unfortunately I do not, as there are 10,000+ potential topic IDs...

Answer (score 0):

From the details you provided I agree the only way is to use `if` (despite the fact `if` is not recommended generally). Try this:

```
location /forum/index.php {
  if ($arg_topic != "") {
    rewrite ^ /forum/vbseo301.php?action=thread&oldid=$arg_topic? break;
  }
}
```

I shall leave my previous answer as it might be of help for someone else.

**Simpler example to make sure this works**

I've put a simpler example to show this works. Here it is the Nginx configuration fragment:

```
location /index.html {
    if ($arg_topic != '') {
        rewrite ^ /vv.html?t=$arg_topic? break;
    }
    ssi on;
    root /home/alaz;
}

location /vv.html {
    ssi on;
    root /home/alaz;
}
```

`index.html` contents:

```
<b>index</b>
<br/>
topic: <!--#echo var="arg_topic" -->
```

`vv.html` contents:

```
<b>vv</b>
<br/>
topic: <!--#echo var="arg_topic" -->
<br/>
t: <!--#echo var="arg_t" -->
```

Now reload Nginx and point your browser to http://hostname/index.html at the first and http://hostname/index.html?topic=11 after that.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - just tried it, still doesn't work. It just stays on index.php, which makes me think the "if ($arg_topc != "") is not working?

Comment: I've created a simple demo for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems lots of people are still viewing this question. Hope  my answer helps!

```
location /forum/index.php {
  if ($args ~ "topic=([0-9]+)"){
    rewrite ^/forum/index\.php$ /forum/vbseo301.php?action=thread&oldid=$arg_topic? last;
  }
}
```

Tested and it works. A couple of critical but subtle fixes in the rewrite line:

1. I removed the query string part "?topic=(.+)" from the old url because nginx rewrite rule doesn't match query strings at all(also called args in nginx). It only tries to match PATH. [reference link](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)
2. The argument topic=xxxx is automatically stored in nginx in this variable: $arg_topic. So I can simply put "oldid=$arg_topic" in the new url. [reference link](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24arg_PARAMETER)
3. I put a question mark "?" at the end of the new url so that nginx won't try to attach the query string from the old url. By default, nginx will attach the entire query string from the old url.

Comment: Note: rewrite ... last;  is fine inside if block, as mentioned in http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil