# Make Codeigniter 2.1.3 allow a Facebook backlink

Tags: php, codeigniter

It happens that I need to fix a Codeigniter issue urgently while being in no way familiar with the tool.

Simple question: how do I allow **links back from Facebook** like http://www.xxx.de/?fb_action_ids=4811819099741&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%224811819099741%22%3A447766801925104%7D&action_type_map=%7B%224811819099741%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

without creating either the infamous *The URI you submitted has disallowed characters* - which I can fix by setting $config['permitted_uri_chars'] - and neither a 404 because of the internal redirects of CI.

I'd love to learn of a quick fix for that issue.

Comment: Can you have the back links hit a controller? i.e. `domain.com/back/?fb....etc`?

Comment: @Brendan: Sorry, being a .NET guy who has never touched Codeigniter, I don't even know where to look. I'm really just looking for a quick fix that survives until tomorrow...

Comment: I mean, are you able to modify how facebook creates the link? or do the params always get placed directly in the root?

Comment: No, can't influence Facebook, besides lots of likes are already out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `.htaccess` you can redirect to wherever. This avoids any CI intricacies.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^ /index.php/? [L]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4227616/183254

---

update: possible working rewrite for nginx

```
if ($args ~ fb_action_ids=(\d+)){
    rewrite ^ http://example.com/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, too bad I forgot to mention: this stuff is running on nginx, not Apache. But there's also the possibility to rewrite, I am sure. Good idea.

Comment: Yup. Lots of nginx rewrite stuff out there. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11305851/183254 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2442374/183254

Answer (score 1):

Set these vars in application/config/config.php:

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE; // This is normally FALSE
```

Adjust `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` if necessary. Mine are `a-z 0-9~%.:_\-#!` and work for almost everything.

I'm not sure what you need to do with the fb data, so all I can say is that with those options set, you should, in theory, be able to access the get vars supplied by facebook.

Comment: Thanks for this, but we went with the rewrite idea of stormdrain. In fact, as I tried to say in the question, we don't need the fb vars, we just don't want to produce errors or 404s.

Answer (score 1):

codeigniter expects the first part of the URI to be the controller it loads, then the second will be the method, and every segment after that are the parameters for the method that gets loaded. A fast solution is set up a route with a regular expression like you would in MVC3 and point it to a controller and method. You can then parse the uri from there.

Match ?fb_action_ids and change it to /controller/method/?fb_action_ids and go from there. Perhaps with a little more information I could help you even further but if this works for you this should be the quickest way to get up back up and running without having to reconfigure a bunch of things.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Thanks! We went with the rewrite solution, but I will forward this to the guy who does the CI stuff. Sounds like a more clean solution.